# Using INNER JOIN in ASP with HTML

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic

Beginner question.
I have a database file with 2 tables - Products and Orders, and with the following SQL:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.CustomerName, Products.ProductName, Products.Price
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Products.ProductID=Orders.PIDSelect
WHERE Orders.OrderID=1;
```

It worked fine in Access, but the ASP is failed and garbled.

First I have a HTML file to ask for an input of the order ID, and want to use ASP to generate the SQL result. Here's the code:

```
<%@ Language="JavaScript" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <%
        var OrderId = Request.Form("OrderId");
        var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
        var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
        conn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='...PATH....mdb'");
        rs.Open("SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.CustomerName, Products.ProductName, Products.Price FROM Products INNER JOIN Orders ON Products.ProductID = Orders.PIDSelect WHERE Orders.OrderID = '" + OrderId + "'", conn);
    %>
    
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Order ID</th>
                <th>Order Date</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <% while (rs.EOF != true) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%Response.Write(rs("Orders.OrderID")) %></td>
                <td><%Response.Write(rs("Orders.TodayDate")) %></td>
                <td><%Response.Write(rs("Orders.CustomerName")) %></td>
                <td><%Response.Write(rs("Products.ProductName")) %></td>
                <td><%Response.Write(rs("Products.Price")) %></td>
            </tr>
            <% rs.MoveNext();
                } %>
        </table>
    <%
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure how to modify the code. Looking for help, thanks!

Comment: there are could be many reasons, e.g. what value do you get here `var OrderId = Request.Form("OrderId");`? try to set fixed value i.e. `var OrderId = 1;` and see if you get same error. And read about sql injections.

Comment: "Failed and garbled" - Doesn’t give us a lot to go on. Garbled suggests character issues likely due to an encoding mismatch but that’s pure guess work on my part.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  If so could you share it with us?

Comment: `Orders.TodayDate` is not there in the select list of the sql.

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason to transform ASP to Javascript?
Why didn't you use pure ASP? So you can catch errors with err.description.
Flakes is right: you have forgotten orders.todayDate.
An other error can be, that you are writing `<%Response.Write(rs("Orders.OrderID")) %>`
You have only use the table name, if the fieldname exists in both tables.

If you want you can try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <%
        OrderId = Request.Form("OrderId");
        SET conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        SET rs       = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")       
        
        ' Newer Version Requires database Engine 2010: conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\inetpub\database\access.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=XX;"
        conn.open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\inetpub\database\access.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database;"
        rs.Open "SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.CustomerName, Orders.TodayDate, Products.ProductName, Products.Price FROM Products INNER JOIN Orders ON Products.ProductID = Orders.PIDSelect WHERE Orders.OrderID = '" & OrderId & "'",conn
    %>
    
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Order ID</th>
                <th>Order Date</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <% do while not rs.eof %>
            <tr>
                <td><%Response.Write(rs("OrderID")) %></td>
                <td><%Response.Write(rs("TodayDate")) %></td>
                <td><%Response.Write(rs("CustomerName")) %></td>
                <td><%Response.Write(rs("ProductName")) %></td>
                <td><%Response.Write(rs("Price")) %></td>
            </tr>
            <% 
            rs.MoveNext
            loop
            %>
        </table>
    <%
        rs.close
        conn.close
    %>
</body>
</html>
```